# How to build Sandboxed app without XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, sandbox

How to build Sandboxed app without XCode? I mean I'm using gcc Make to build my applications and own system for creating app bundles. But how can I enable the Sandbox without using XCode and option it's Sandbox option?

There's tut about Sandbox, but I can't find anywhere informations about enabling Sandbox, but still no about SB without XCode.. Anyone can help?
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2

Comment: does your app have an Info.plist file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty easy to code-sign your application outside of Xcode. Simply create your entitlements in a separate plist file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Once you have it, simply issue this command to code-sign your app bundle and enable sandboxing, by making it part of the entitlements:

```
codesign -s - -f --entitlements /path/to/entitlement.plist /path/to/YourApp.app/
```

If you already code-sign with a certificate, just replace '-s -' above with '-s "3rd Party Macintosh Developer..." and use your developer certificate.

Comment: What if I don't want my app to be sandboxed?  The app I'm writing will probably never be distributed on the app store, since it's specific to one particular hardware product; plus it requires services/capabilities that are likely not available from within the sandbox.  Can I just codesign an app with my developer ID without specifying any entitlements, sandboxing, etc.?  Would removing the "--entitlements <file" option work for that?

Comment: Yes. But this question was about a sandboxed app!

Comment: Is asking a one-off/tangential question like the one I did in the way that I did not kosher then?  Did I really need to open a new topic for it?

Comment: You're probably better off asking a new question, that way we all benefit since it's easier to read and search. Cheers!

Comment: I tried the `codesign` command as indicated in this answer but when I start the signed application, the activity monitor says that the application is not sandboxed. Can it be that this information is outdated?