# What is required for an OS X app to run in sandbox mode?

Tags: macos, sandbox

I have signed my OS X application including the sandbox entitlement as described here:
[How to build Sandboxed app without XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385252/how-to-build-sandboxed-app-without-xcode)

But when I open the application it runs outside the sandbox.  That is, in the Activity Monitor the process is listed with Sandbox = No.

What else do I need to do to ensure the application runs in sandbox mode?

(Note: I'm running OS X 10.7.4)

Comment: Have you tried following the apple docs instead?  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW3

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer - the problem is that all the apple documentation seems to assume that your application is built by XCode, but mine isn't.

Comment: Ah I see my bad, I didn't notice the link name.  Though it'd be better next time if you stated it in the question.